# Using methods of classes that its didn't extends the same parent class

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm using Processing, and I have a method (`smooth()` here) that I would like to use for `PApplet` object when I draw in the window and for `PGraphics` when I draw in a image.

The problem is, theses two classes (`PApplet` & `PGraphics`) extends only from the `Object` class and Eclipse said I must choice between the `PApplet` cast or the `PGraphics` cast but i want to use both in this case.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Hi!  You'll have a much better chance at getting some good help if you could add the code that's giving you the problem, i.e. where/how are you trying to cast to both classes, and what exactly is the Eclipse error.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a magical way to support two completely different types. There are a couple workarounds though.

You could use **overloading** which means creating separate functions for each type. Something like this:

```
void drawRect(PGraphics pg){
  pg.rect(1, 2, 3, 4);
}

void drawRect(PApplet p){
  p.rect(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Or you could rely on the fact that the `PApplet` class has a `g` variable that references its internal `PGraphics` instance. Then you'd only need one function that takes a `PGraphics` and pass in the `g` variable when you had a `PApplet` instance. Something like this:

```
void setup(){
 size(500, 500); 
}

void draw(){
 drawCircle(g); 
}

void drawCircle(PGraphics pg){
  pg.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}
```

This approach is a bit hacky, so an even better solution would be to refactor your `PApplet` code so it always draws to a `PGraphics` explicitly. Then you could pass that `PGraphics` instance to your function.